# Dynamic Roles/Hierarchy with SimpleMembership

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, authorization, simplemembership

I finally got my MVC 4 application all set up with SimpleMembership, but now have run into a new problem.  I have a menu system (in a sidebar) that gives users access to various functionality throughout the app.  I recently realized that, in order to be somewhat user-friendly, I need to disable or remove various menu links based on roles.  So I set up a role system and a relationship to these menu links, which works perfectly.  However, the "basic site access" role **should not** have access to **all** of the links in the menu (and their corresponding controllers/actions).  Previously, I had given site access by simply applying the `Authorize` attribute globally, via my filter config:

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
{
    filters.Add(new AuthorizeAttribute());
}
```

Now I've figured out that, in order to control "basic" access to the app, I would need to add individual `Authorize` attributes at the action level (with the "admin" role having full access).  While this is fine, albeit somewhat annoying, it doesn't seem very scalable.  What if my client adds a new role through the administration interface and wants to control access to various tasks?  I have already coded the menu system to disable links dynamically, based on what roles have access to which tasks.  But there's no way (that I know of) to dynamically apply different roles to the `Authorize` attribute.

Though I've read about [why SimpleMembership may not be the bee's knees](http://brockallen.com/2012/09/02/think-twice-about-using-membershipprovider-and-simplemembership/), I've just finished migrating from ASP.NET Membership (which had *serious* shortcomings of its own), and I certainly do **not** want to roll my own user/role management system.  Has anyone successfully implemented something to handle this scenario?

Answer (score 2):

You should definitely take a look at [Fluent Security](http://www.fluentsecurity.net/) if you have a lot of controllers/actions that you don't want to decorate with annotations.

It allows all authorisation to be handled from Global.asax. It's well documented and there's a good tutorial on it [here](http://blog.mariusschulz.com/securing-an-aspnet-mvc-application-using-fluentsecurity).

Comment: I had never heard of this, but it looks very promising.  Thanks!  I'm going to leave this question open for a bit to see if anyone else wants to weigh in.

Comment: Did Fluent Security meet your requirements?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't had time to implement it yet!  I will certainly post again when I get the chance to play with it.

Comment: It's been a while and the link is dead now, found [this on github](https://github.com/kristofferahl/FluentSecurity/wiki)